# how to check membership of keys and values a dictionaries in python with user defined function

Tags: python, function, user-defined-functions, defined

something like this but in a defined function

```
# Check if a key exists in a dictionary
info = {'Breakfast': 'Egg', 'time' :'05:30 am'}
if 'lunch' in info.keys():
    print('Exists!')
else:
    print("Doesn't exist!")
```

Comment: What exactly you mean? Please clarify your question as of now your question is not clear.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one liner:

```
def key_in_dict(d, key):
    return 'Exists!' if key in d else "Doesn't exist!"
```